# xslt code to update cdata segment in my map

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xslt code to update cdata segment under arg1 segment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:ws="http://ws.myimm.htp.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s0="http://AIS/IL/ES/QueryIndividualReq/JIM/v1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"  />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:records" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:records">
    <soapenv:Envelope>
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ws:incoming>
          <arg0>IH035</arg0>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <arg1>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>

            <root>
              <agencyId>AGF</agencyId>
              <password>password</password>
              <records>
                <xsl:copy-of select="item"/>
              </records>
            </root>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
            ]]&gt;</xsl:text>
          </arg1>
        </ws:incoming>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input which i am passing to this xslt code is

Input

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<records xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://AIS/IL/ES/QueryIndividualReq/JIM/v1.0">
  <item xmlns="">
    <txn_id>1</txn_id>
    <name>Ali Imran Mutalib</name>
    <ppt_no>001FILIPINA</ppt_no>
    <nat_cd>PHL</nat_cd>
    <dob>19800101</dob>
    <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
    <ppt_exp_dt>22102019</ppt_exp_dt>
    <roc_no>591104-07-5347</roc_no>
  </item>
</records>
```

Output result is

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.myimm.htp.com/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ws:incoming>
      <arg0>IH035</arg0>
      <arg1><![CDATA[<root><agencyId>AGF</agencyId><password>password</password><records><item xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <txn_id>1</txn_id>
    <name>Ali Imran Mutalib</name>
    <ppt_no>001FILIPINA</ppt_no>
    <nat_cd>PHL</nat_cd>
    <dob>19800101</dob>
    <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
    <ppt_exp_dt>22102019</ppt_exp_dt>
    <roc_no>591104-07-5347</roc_no>
  </item></records></root>
            ]]></arg1>
    </ws:incoming>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But i need the output to be in this format

```
    <soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ws="http://ws.myimm.htp.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:incoming>
         <arg0>IH035</arg0>
        <arg1>
        <![CDATA[
            <root>
                <agencyId>AGF</agencyId>
                <password>password</password>
                <records>
                    <item>
                        <txn_id>1</txn_id>
                        <name>Ali Imran Mutalib</name>
                        <ppt_no>001FILIPINA</ppt_no>
                        <nat_cd>PHL</nat_cd>
                        <dob>19800101</dob>
                        <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
                        <ppt_exp_dt>22102019</ppt_exp_dt>
                        <roc_no>591104-07-5347</roc_no>
                    </item>
                </records>
            </root>
            ]]>
        </arg1>
      </ws:incoming>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can i achive this.Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to remove the namespace declarations from the copied `item`, change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="item"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
```

and add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that your first template is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:ws="http://ws.myimm.htp.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s0="http://AIS/IL/ES/QueryIndividualReq/JIM/v1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"  />
  <xsl:template match="/s0:records">
    <soapenv:Envelope>
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ws:incoming>
          <arg0>IH035</arg0>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <arg1>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <root>
              <agencyId>AGF</agencyId>
              <password>password</password>           
              <records>
              <item>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </item>
              </records>              
            </root>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
            ]]&gt;</xsl:text>
          </arg1>
        </ws:incoming>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:records/item/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```